# 2 examples to try to understand partials derivatives and deriviability

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, partial-derivative

To prove that a functions has partial derivatives every partial has to exist, and every partial exist only if the limit of definition of partial exist. Is this right?

Then if partials  exist ,and the limit of derivability involving the Jacobian is equal to zero, ([see Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions)), then you can say it is derivable. Do you have to check this limit every time to see if is differentiable? Or there is another procedure?

And how to check the partial derivatives are continuous? Do you just see if the partials have one or some points of discontinuity by just looking at the partials functions, and then if they are to be continuous they are differentiable? And if is a piecewise function every branch of every partial must be equal for where f changes  between branchs?
In the following 2 examples I try to address this questions.

If f is define as$$f(x,y) =\begin{cases} x^2+2x+5y+10 & \text{ for } (x,y)>= (0,0) \\ y^2+2y+x+10  & \text{ for } (x,y)<(0,0) \end{cases}$$

And its partials $$f^\prime_x(x,y) =\begin{cases} 2x+2 & \text{ for } (x,y)>=(0,0) \\ 1& \text{ for } (x,y)<(0,0) \end{cases}$$

$$f^\prime_y(x,y) =\begin{cases} 5 & \text{ for } (x,y)>= (0,0) \\ 2y+2 & \text{ for } (x,y)<(0,0) \end{cases}$$

Can I do this, do a branch partials like above? And the partials are continuous? I think not because $$f^\prime_x(0,0) =\begin{cases} 2 & \text{ for } (x,y)>=(0,0) \\ 1& \text{ for } (x,y)<(0,0) \end{cases}$$ $$f^\prime_y(0,0) =\begin{cases} 5 & \text{ for } (x,y)>= (0,0) \\ 2 & \text{ for } (x,y)<(0,0) \end{cases}$$ so they are not continuous on point (0,0) is that right?

However f is continuous? Plug in (0,0) in the function and you get $$f(x,y) =\begin{cases} 10 & \text{ for } (x,y)>= (0,0) \\ 10  & \text{ for } (x,y)<(0,0) \end{cases}$$ However, I am not convince for example 1st and 3rd quadrants I can see is true but for 2d and 4th wish function takes place?

Now if f was slightly different $$g(x,y) =\begin{cases} x^2+2x+3y+10 & \text{ for } (x,y)= (0,0) \\ y^2+3y+2x+5  & \text{ for } (x,y)\neq (0,0) \end{cases}$$

Its partials

$$g^\prime_x(x,y) =\begin{cases} 2x+2 & \text{ for } (x,y)=(0,0) \\ 2& \text{ for } (x,y) \neq (0,0) \end{cases}$$

$$g^\prime_y(0,0) =\begin{cases} 3  & \text{ for } (x,y)= (0,0) \\ 2y+3 & \text{ for } (x,y) \neq (0,0) \end{cases}$$

$$g^\prime_x(0,0) =\begin{cases} 2 & \text{ for } (x,y)=(0,0) \\ 2& \text{ for } (x,y) \neq (0,0) \end{cases}$$

$$g^\prime_y(0,0) =\begin{cases} 3  & \text{ for } (x,y)= (0,0) \\ 3 & \text{ for } (x,y) \neq (0,0) \end{cases}$$

So it seems that the partials are continuous therefore g  is derivable therefore continuous but g is not continuous on(0,0) $$g(0,0) =\begin{cases} 10 & \text{ for } (x,y)= (0,0) \\ +5  & \text{ for } (x,y)\neq (0,0) \end{cases}$$ so it is not derivable and hence its partials are not continuous but they are.

So what is wrong in this second case and with first one? If you can please provide with a detailed answer to the 2 examples, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Please do not clutter the site by adding things like "can someone answer" or "please reply" to titles. It's clear to everyone that you'd like to get an answer, since you asked a question.

Comment: OK. what happens when the question is not answer for a long time that it don't appear on the new question and people just don't notice?how can i put on top so people can see it? @Thursday

Comment: In my previous post i wasn't referring to my question only but to all the questions being posted,it seem nobody was answering any question and that could be something relating to a site problem @Thursday

Comment: @studentNk you could use bounties once you have enough reputation, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) for more info.

Comment: What do you mean by $(x,y)\geq(0,0)$ and $(x,y)<(0,0)$?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I am not sure if it is applyable but where x and y are only positive and 0 for the first case and x any y only negative for the second case,is that possible to describe?and also I would like to ask what happens when x is positive and y negative and the opposite what function takes place?or is not define like for f(x)= log(x) x<0 not defined?or you only can do that with one variable like y>0 for multivariable function?or even do separate x>2;y>5?

Comment: When you want to discuss questions of this sort you have to define $(x,y)\mapsto f(x,y)$ in a *full neighborhood* of the origin. Only then one is able to check whether $f_x$, $f_y$ are continuous at $(0,0)$, etc.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I understand but at the same time no, because it can have partials without being continuous.or no?because if f is not define there no point to be dervable and even for partials.?it must be f continues even for partials??

Comment: I am going to answer my own comment but correct if I am wrong.to talk about partials and derivability on a single point it as to be continuous and therefore a neighborhood where f is defined, otherwise not applicable.

Comment: Is it f continuous on (0,0) I think so because f(0,0)=10=f(0,0)=10 is this right ? And the partials are not continuous? @ChristianBlatter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a function is discontinuous at some point then is no point talk about partials and hence derivative. A function can have a partials however they could not be define ate some points and hence discontinuous partials .however if at points where the partials could be discontinuos exist like $f^\prime_x =\lim_{h \to 0}$ $\frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}$ then is said to be derivable at that point (?however partials could be discontinuous?)

Then if the partials are define at every point is said to have continuous partials and hence derivable.

For a picewise function besides to check continuity in each branch you have to check continuity where piecewise function change between branches and then if is continuous you have see if the partials are continues at those points betweens branches.

For the first case

Since the function is  not continuous on (0,0) because the function is not defined at (-x,y) and (x,-y) ( by another words is not define in a full neiberhood at origin) so the partials are not define, but even f was  then we check if a function has partials, and it has, however they are not continuous as obvious express in the question

For the 2sd case

First of all, you can just write g(x,y)=10 if (x,y)=(0,0), there is no point in writing that way. This way you can also see that is pointless in differentiating x2+2x+3y+10 with the usual rules, as it is only valid in one point and derivatives deal with neighbourhoods. Finally, the "contradiction" is explained by remembering that the usual rules for differentiating only make sense if the derivative is defined, and if the function is not continuos they are not defined.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need 2 dimensions to understand this. Consider fir your first example
$f(x) = |x|$ in 1D - it is clearly continuous and not differentiable at zero, as your first example was. So such a thing is possible.

Similarly, consider $f(x) = x$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(0) = 1$. Clearly $f$ is not continuous (and hence, by definition, not differentiable) at $x=0$. However, $f$ has a continuous continuation, $g(x)=x$, which is differentiable.

Comment: I understand it but I have difficulty In translating that to several variables because if the partials are continuous then is derivable and hence it has partials and is continuous. now taken from the opposite direction if its partials exit and is continuous then is not sure it is derivable and then if it is derivable is not sure that has continuous partials.now how can you see it has partials is from definition of partial that is $f^\prime_x=lim_$\h \rightarrow \o \frac {f(x+h_x)-f(x)}{h}$? and to see it is derivable is this limit ...

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions and how do we see that if is derivable it has also has partials continuous?and how we check it has partials continuous without checking it is derivable? @gt6989b

Comment: but isn't that a function is diferentiable even if is just one point?and forf(x)=x for x≠0 and f(0)=1 would be everywhere except x=0?

Comment: A discontinuous function is not differentiable. In any number of dimensions. You can design a continuous variant that would be differentiable, but that would not be the function itself.

Comment: I understand you. But is Differentiability is $\neq $ than saying derivability ? @gt6989b